# Erro com valores NULL em um data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, null

Olá,

Estou trabalhando na construção de um data frame em R a partir de um JSON que recebo depois de fazer um GET em um serviço, porém estou recebendo um erro pois um dos valores do JSON de retorno está como null, segue trecho do código utilizado:

```
    id <- callback$data$id
    uri <- callback$data$uri
    name <- callback$data$name
    email <- callback$data$email
    status <- callback$data$status

data <- data.frame(id,
                   uri,
                   name,
                   email,
                   status) 


  data <- tibble::as_tibble(data)
```

Segue JSON de retorno:

```
  “data”: {
    "id": 7658,
    "uri": "https://sampleuri.io/samples”,
    “name”: “A return example“,
    “email”: null,
    “status”: “ACTIVE”,
   }
```

Segue erro:

**Error in data.frame(id, uri, name, email, status,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0**

Testei removendo a variável email e o data frame é criado corretamente, alguem poderia me ajudar numa maneira de fazer o R aceitar o valor nulo da variável email?

Desde já agradeço muito a ajuda.

Comment: Mude para `NA`: talvez `sub('null', 'NA', callback$data$email)`. Isso acontece porque `length(NULL)` é igual a 0.

Comment: Olá @RuiBarradas muito obrigado pela dica, deu certo :D